# Wordpress image returns 403 on Safari when setting w (width) and crop queries

Tags: safari

I have an image in my page pointing to the following URL hosted using Wordpress engine: https://content.thriveglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/shutterstock_1450164881.jpg?w=1200&crop=0,0,100,78

When loading the image on Chrome and Firefox, the image loads without a problem, but when loading it on Safari, the request returns a 403 for the image. If I remove one of the 2 attributes on query string, it works just fine, but requesting with `?w=1200&crop=0,0,100,78` or `?crop=0,0,100,78&w=1200`, it returns 403 only on Safari.

I also noticed that I can apply both attributes when the format is `.jpeg` instead of `.jpg`. Is there a real explanation to this behavior on Safari alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made some testing on my own across all browser, virtually and with physical devices. I can't reproduce your problem.

If there was a problem I would say it's coming from the url encoding, probably the coma's.

| Character | From UTF-8 |
| --- | --- |
| `,` | `%2C` |

- Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Replacing the coma's encoding by `%2C` might solve your problem. Try the following.

```
?w=1200&crop=0%2C0%2C100%2C78
```

https://content.thriveglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/shutterstock_1450164881.jpg?w=1200&crop=0%2C0%2C100%2C78

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what the issue was, but when trying later, I could get the image correctly, so it should be a server issue concerning only Safari user agent.